# Is there an automatic way of identifying transitive verbs in Computational Linguistics?

Tags: computational-linguistics, english, verbs, corpora

Is there any straightforward way of identifying transitive verbs (or sentences containing transitive constructions) in an BrE English text?

I've looked into semantic shallow parsers, such as [Semafor](http://code.google.com/p/semafor-semantic-parser/), but these don't seem to offer the straightforward approach I'm looking for.

Comment: For which language? I doubt there is a one-solution-fits-any-language for doing this.

Comment: @kaleissin For UK English. :)

Comment: @Julie With "UK English" you mean British English? Or really all of the UK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsers for rich formalisms like [C&C](http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc) and [Enju](http://www-tsujii.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/enju/) come with super-taggers. Super-taggers are quite like [part-of-speech (POS) taggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging), except that the tags they produce have more information.

For example, C&C produces:

```
word="undergone" lemma="undergo" pos="VBN" chunk="I-VP" cat="(S[pt]\NP)/NP"
```

The *cat* tells you that this is a verb that takes an NP on the right, and then one on the left to form an S.

However, things are not always this straight-forward. For "added constantly to the list", we get:

```
   word="added" lemma="add" pos="VBN" chunk="I-VP" cat="(S[pt]\NP)/PP"
   word="constantly" lemma="constantly" pos="RB" chunk="I-ADVP" cat="(S\NP)\(S\NP)"
   word="to" lemma="to" pos="TO" chunk="I-PP" cat="PP/NP"
   word="the" lemma="the" pos="DT" chunk="I-NP" cat="NP[nb]/N"
   word="list" lemma="list" pos="NN" chunk="I-NP" cat="N"
```

"added", here is transitive, but one of its arguments is a PP. However, not all PPs fill valency slots.

I have no idea if you would find it more straight-forward than Semafor, or less. [Boxer](http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/boxer) would give you [discourse representation structures (DRSes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_representation_structure#Discourse_Representation_Structures) which include the kind of info of the Semafor output. I suppose you'll have to evaluate it for yourself.